# Turn select into Update with multiple joins Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

So it's the first time i want to make a update with on a query with multiple joins.

Database = Postgres v.10

This is what i tried so far:

```
update table1 t1 set t4.datum = t1.datum
from table1 t1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null
```

Error : SQL Error [42712]: ERROR: table name "t1" specified more than once

Next try:

```
update table1 t1 set t4.datum = t.datum
from table1 t
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null
```

Error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "t4" of relation "table1" does not exist
Position: 28

Last try:

```
update table1 t1 set t4.datum = t.datum
from table1 t
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t1.id = t.id and t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null
```

Error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "t4" of relation "table1" does not exist
Position: 28

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't repeat the target table of an UPDATE in the FROM clause. So something like. The assignment `set t4.datum = t.datum` also seems wrong. If you want to update `table1` you can't reference `t4` on the left hand side of the assignment. Additionally the target columns can't be "table qualified" inside the SET part (as it's clear which table's column is meant)

So I think you are looking for something like this:

```
update table1 t1 
   set datum = t4.datum
from table3 t3 
  inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t1.id = t3.id 
  and t3.id = 550 
  and t4.scale is not null 
  and t4.datum is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the alias for the table in the FROM clause and then use that throughout. I think I edited this correctly:

```
update t1 set t4.datum = t1.datum
from table1 t1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null;
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because want to update `t4.datum` from table `table1`.

You should change set column `t4.datum = t1.datum` to `t1.datum = t4.datum` Becuase you want update `table1` (Update query: `update table1 t1`) and `t4.datum` not reference to `table1`

Should change query like below (If you want update `table1`):

```sql
update table1 t1 set t1.datum = t4.datum
from table1 t
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t1.id = t.id and t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null
```

---

**Edited**

Query for update `table4`:

```sql
update table4 u_t4 set datum = t1.datum
from table1 t1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
inner join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
where t4.id = u_t4.id and t3.id = 550 and t4.scale is not null and t4.datum is null
```

Comment: True i made a mistake with the tables. Actually i want to update table4 since the t4.datum is in that table

Comment: I edited post for update `table4`